# Proof that the Borel hierarchy on $\mathbb{R}$ collapses after $\omega_1$ steps.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, descriptive-set-theory

I want to proof that the Borel hierarchy on $\mathbb{R}$ collapses after $\omega_1$ steps. However, I'm stuck and don't know where to begin, I suspect I need to use the fact that $\aleph_1$ is a regular cardinal and the first uncountable cardinal. I'd like to know some hints on where to continue.
Thanks.

Comment: Write down your steps, constructing a sigma-algebra.  $\mathcal G_0$ = open sets; $\mathcal G_\alpha = \cdots$ for ordinals $\alpha > 0$.  Use that precise induction step to show $\mathcal G_{\omega_1+1} = \mathcal G_{\omega_1}$.  But YOU have to do it, not us.

Comment: A key fact in the proof I know is that for each countable set of countable ordinals, there exists a countable ordinal greater than each of the ordinals in the countable set. Equivalently, the supremum of a countable collection of countable ordinals is countable.

Comment: This should follow from the fact that $\omega_1$ is a regular cardinal.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro this is a key fact in any proof, indeed in ZF we can have that $\omega_1$ is singular and the Borel hierarchy can have pretty much any length (could be as short as four steps but could also have much more than $\omega_1$ steps)

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti: Because I'm not very knowledgeable about axiomatic set-theoretic matters, I intentionally used the phrase "the proof I know" to keep from possibly making a too strong statement. Also, since I almost never bother with non-AC mathematics (other than being vaguely aware of the many flavors of non-AC'ness, and being aware of some things that can "go wrong" within some of these flavors), I wasn't thinking of the situation when AC fails in various ways when I made my previous comment. **(continued)**

Comment: However, your comment about the Borel hierarchy length possibly being four reminds me of [this 30 July 2001 sci.math question of mine](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/HlZFLPi-eWE/m/YZxXT0lVWXQJ) and these follow-ups -- [1-2 January 2006](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/5lmqxsLJVkI/m/inwEKvcapSoJ) and [2 January 2006](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/hle75frOeew/m/AiPaXnH6dhwJ).

Comment: Thank you so much @AlessandroCodenotti , didn't see that fact.